# Extract values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
        $familia = array
        (
            "JONATHAN"=>"HERMANO",
            "Joan"=>"hermana",
            "Ruth"=>"mama",
            "Alejandro"=>"papa"
        );
```

I want to extract just one value from the array, for example("Jonathan"=>"hermano"), to do 
echo JONATHAN es mi HERMANO

I know that is common to use "foreach" and "as", but i just want one value.

Comment: just use `key()` and `current() / reset()`

Comment: I would say `reset($familia)` then `key($familia); current($familia);`

Comment: just for fun: http://ideone.com/fvN2Xd